# Cisco Unity call manager - deleting users within an LDAP setup

Tags: cisco

We have just installed VOIP on the network and AD has been setup to sync with the CUCM which works just fine at the moment. However I need to delete a user from the CUCM (user no longer requires a phone but is still an employee) but am currently unable to do so - I get a message stating that "the add delete functions have been disabled because the user directory is in sync with LDAP".

What I need to know is what options, if any, do I have for deleting a user from CUCM without deleting the account from AD.

Would the operation be immediate or or there a time factor involved.
Also what happens to the CUCM user accounts in general if I disable an AD user account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late, but ran into this the other day.

The only way to get them out of CUCM is to delete them in AD, ore remove their last name in AD.  You can delete the phones/device profiles, but not the users.